# phalcon : how to infinite categories?

Tags: php, orm, model, relationship, phalcon

i have a table like this :

```
category_id
parent_category_id
category_name
```

i want to make infinite category loop so i want to use hasOne, hasMany, belongsTo relations words but how can i do that ?

this is my category class:

```
<?php

use \Phalcon\Mvc\Model;

class Category extends Model{

    public $category_id;

    public $parent_category_id;

    public $name;

    public $image;

    public $description;

    public function initialize()
    {
        /**
         * every category has only one parent category
         */
        $this->hasOne('category_id', 'Category', 'parent_category_id', ['alias' => 'category_id']);
    }
}
```

is it wrong ? and what is the best solution ? 
p.s. : i want to learn how could be done it ? ( give me  suggestions )

Comment: Unfortunately, the question sounds totally unclear. What infinite loop do you need? What do you want to do in it? Your code has no loop at all...

Comment: @YakovL, he wants to create a chain relation between a bunch of categories.

Comment: @Timothy, you are right and i have been trying since 2 days but not complete

Comment: Does the answer I posted help you?

Comment: i have no time for try ... i will back to you as soon @Timothy ...

Answer (score 1):

The relation you defined will only allow you to make a 1 on 1 relation.
Meaning, each category only has 1 parent **and** 1 parent only has 1 child.
I am guessing this isn't the behaviour you are looking for.

```
$this->hasOne('category_id', 'Category', 'parent_category_id', ['alias' => 'category_id']);
```

Here is an example of a 1 to N relation where 1 category can have 1 parent **and** 1 parent can have multiple children.

To avoid confusion you should give the relations a meaningful alias.

```
public function initialize()
{
    // a category can have multiple child categories 
    $this->hasMany('category_id', 'Category', 'parent_category_id', ['alias' => 'child_categories']);

    // a category only has one parent category
    $this->belongsTo('parent_category_id', 'Category', 'category_id', ['alias' => 'parent_category']);
}
```

You can use the above relations as follows
(note that [there are also other methods to request related data](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/models.html#taking-advantage-of-relationships))

```
// will return an array of Category objects. Because our relation was "hasMany"
$categoryChildren = $category->getRelated('child_categories');

// will return a single Category object. Because we can only have one parent
$categoryParent = $category->getRelated('parent_category');
```

---

**Example:** 
Lets say you have to following data:

```
category_id | parent_category_id | category_name
----------- | ------------------ | -------------
1           | null               | A
2           | 1                  | B
3           | 1                  | C
4           | 2                  | D
5           | 4                  | E

// returns categories: B, C
$category = Category::findFirstById(1)->getRelated('child_categories');
// returns categories: null
$category = Category::findFirstById(1)->getRelated('parent_category');

// return categories: D
$category = Category::findFirstById(2)->getRelated('child_categories');   
// returns categories: A
$category = Category::findFirstById(2)->getRelated('parent_category');

// return categories: null
$category = Category::findFirstById(3)->getRelated('child_categories'); 
// returns categories: A
$category = Category::findFirstById(3)->getRelated('parent_category');

// return categories: E
$category = Category::findFirstById(4)->getRelated('child_categories');
// returns categories: B
$category = Category::findFirstById(4)->getRelated('parent_category');

// return categories: null
$category = Category::findFirstById(5)->getRelated('child_categories');
// returns categories: D
$category = Category::findFirstById(5)->getRelated('parent_category');

// returns categories: B
$category = Category::findFirstById(5)->getRelated('parent_category')->getRelated('parent_category');
```

As you can see with the last example, you can create a chain of categories.

Comment: @Timotythank you very very much for helping . i will use it and go back to share result with you . thanks again bro . so thanks .

Comment: @Timothy nice examples, that formatted table alone forces me to upvote you :)